# How to get static image url from flickr URL?

Tags: flickr

Is it possible to get static image URL from the flickr URL via an api call or some script ? 
 
For eg : 

Flickr URL -> http://www.flickr.com/photos/53067560@N00/2658147888/in/set-72157606175084388/

Static image URL -> http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3221/2658147888_826edc8465.jpg

Comment: Yes, really old. But if you, like me, still end up here after googling, check out this link: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html

Comment: Ho i can extract your second url from first one?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In your Flickr URL, the photo ID is 2658147888. You use [flickr.photos.getSizes](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getSizes.html) to get the various sizes of the photo available, and pick the url you want from that, depending on the size. There are several ways to access the API so please specify if you want more details for a particular language.

Answer (score 63):

With specifying `extras=url_o` you get a link to the original image:

```
https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=YOURAPIKEY&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&text=cats&extras=url_o
```

For downscaled images, you use the following parameters: `url_t, url_s, url_q, url_m, url_n, url_z, url_c, url_l`

Alternatively, you can construct the URL [as described](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html):

```
http://farm{farm-id}.staticflickr.com/{server-id}/{id}_{secret}.jpg
or
http://farm{farm-id}.staticflickr.com/{server-id}/{id}_{secret}_[mstzb].jpg
```

Comment: can you please order the parameters(url_t,url_s) based on image quality or atleast specify what each one does

Answer (score 7):

You can also access the original image using the photoId (number before the first underscore)

http://flickr.com/photo.gne?id=photoId

In your case it would be:

https://www.flickr.com/photo.gne?id=2658147888

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if you can get it directly through a single API call, but this link explains how the urls for the images are contructed: [link](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I prefer to construct the link by myself, because making an API call for every image is to slow for me.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some code I wrote to retrieve metadata from a Flickr Photo based on its ID:

I first defined a javascript object `FlickrPhoto` to hold the photo's metadata:

```
function FlickrPhoto(title, owner, flickrURL, imageURL) {
    this.title = title;
    this.owner = owner;
    this.flickrURL = flickrURL;
    this.imageURL = imageURL;
}
```

I then created a `FlickrService` object to hold my [Flickr API Key](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.api_keys.html) and all my ajax calls to the RESTful API.

The `getPhotoInfo` function takes the *Photo ID* as parameter, constructs the appropriate ajax call and passes a `FlickrPhoto` object containing the photo metadata to a *callback* function.

```
function FlickrService() {
    this.flickrApiKey = "763559574f01aba248683d2c09e3f701";
    this.flickrGetInfoURL = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getInfo&nojsoncallback=1&format=json";

    this.getPhotoInfo = function(photoId, callback) {
        var ajaxOptions = {
            type: 'GET',
            url: this.flickrGetInfoURL,
            data: { api_key: this.flickrApiKey, photo_id: photoId },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) { 
                if (data.stat == "ok") {
                    var photo = data.photo;
                    var photoTitle = photo.title._content;
                    var photoOwner = photo.owner.realname;
                    var photoWebURL = photo.urls.url[0]._content;
                    var photoStaticURL = "https://farm" + photo.farm + ".staticflickr.com/" +  photo.server + "/" + photo.id + "_" + photo.secret + "_b.jpg";

                    var flickrPhoto = new FlickrPhoto(photoTitle, photoOwner, photoWebURL, photoStaticURL);
                    callback(flickrPhoto);
                }
            }
        };

        $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
    }
}
```

You can then use the service as follows:

```
var photoId = "11837138576";
var flickrService = new FlickrService();
flickrService.getPhotoInfo(photoId, function(photo) {
    console.log(photo.imageURL);
    console.log(photo.owner);
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Below a solution without using flickr-apis, only standard Linux commands (actually I ran it on MS Windows with [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com)):

- Put your list of URLs in the *tmp* variable
- If you are downloading private photos like me, the protocol will be *https* and you'll need to pass the authentication cookies to *wget*. I log on with a browser (Chrome) and exported the cookies file using an [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookiestxt/njabckikapfpffapmjgojcnbfjonfjfg)
- If you access public URLs, just remove the parameter *--load-cookies $cookies*
- The script downloads in the local folder the photos in their *original format*
- If you want just the URL of the static image, remove the last command *| xargs wget --load-cookies $cookies*

Here the script, you can use it as a start for your explorations:

```
cookies=~/cookies.txt
root="https://www.flickr.com/photos/131469243@N02/"

tmp="https://www.flickr.com/photos/131469243@N02/29765108124/in/album-72157673986011342/
https://www.flickr.com/photos/131469243@N02/29765103724/in/album-72157673986011342/
https://www.flickr.com/photos/131469243@N02/29765102344/in/album-72157673986011342/"

while read -r url; do

    if  [[ $url == http* ]] ;
    then
        url2=$root`echo -n $url | grep -oP '(?<=https://www.flickr.com/photos/131469243@N02/)\w+'`/sizes/o
        wget -q --load-cookies $cookies -O - $url2 | grep -io 'https://c[0-9].staticflickr.com.*_o_d.jpg'  | xargs wget --load-cookies $cookies
    fi
done <<< "$tmp";
```