# Flickr API: How to get URL for sharing each photo in Set

Tags: php, flickr

In my local webserver, I'm trying to generate the text for pasting to my blog, followed by below question:
[How to get static image url from flickr URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803310/how-to-get-static-image-url-from-flickr-url)

```
<a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/53067560@N00/2658147888/" title="Chou fleurs by Nicolas de Fontenay, on Flickr">[<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC7Ng.jpg" width="500" height="375" alt="Chou fleurs">][1]
```

I think it's good to use some API function and to designate $variables to:

- 53067560@N00
- 2658147888
- "Chou fleurs by Nicolas de Fontenay, on Flickr"
- "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3221/2658147888_826edc8465.jpg"
- "500"
- "375"
- "Chou fleurs"

, but don't know how to code in detail. Ideally, a function

```
getFlickrImageURLforGrab(name of Set, # of photos)
```

ex.) getFlickrImageURLforGrab(myset1, 10) returns first 10 photo's URLs in the Set myset1 are displayed. Would you please show a simple php example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers in the question you link to refer to [flickr.photos.getSizes](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getSizes.html).  You also will want to look at the doc for [flickr.photosets.getPhotos](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.getPhotos.html).

I don't use PHP with Flickr's API, but a search turns up [phpFlickr](http://phpflickr.com/), which might help you with some of the heavy lifting.

Comment: Dear David, I appreciate your quick reply. I'm trying to include that API function (though I don't know how to do in detail, unfortunately) / grantaka36