# Flickr camera roll backup with wget or curl

Tags: bash, curl, backup, wget, flickr

How can I backup the camera roll page in flickr with wget or curl as a static page?

```
#!/bin/bash

cookies=/Users/xxx/Downloads/flickr/cookies.txt
root="https://www.flickr.com/photos/xxx"

tmp="https://www.flickr.com/photos/xxx/albums/29765102344/"

while read -r url; do

    if  [[ $url == http* ]] ;
    then
        url2=$root`echo -n $url | grep -o '(?<=https://www.flickr.com/photos/xxx/)\w+'`/sizes/h
        # wget -q --load-cookies $cookies -O - $url2 | grep -io 'https://c[0-9].staticflickr.com.*_o_d.jpg'  | xargs wget --load-cookies $cookies
        wget -q --load-cookies $cookies -O - $url2 | grep -io 'https://live.staticflickr.com.*_h.jpg'  | xargs wget --load-cookies $cookies
    fi
done <<< "$tmp";
```

Code is from [@robermann](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803310/how-to-get-static-image-url-from-flickr-url)

Comment: What happend when you tried to run code you show? Did it what it should? Did some error appears?

Comment: unfortunately nothing happens...